# how to generate index.html- allure reporting- testng-maven-selenium webdriver

Tags: maven, selenium, allure

I am new to allure reporting. I am having selenium testng tests and using maven to run them. After mvn test, a xml file is generated allure-result folder. 
Can anyone tell me how to generate index.html file with this. Do i need to add something in pom.xml. Here is my pom.xml :

```
<properties>
    <allure.version>1.4.13</allure.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-BETA14</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                 <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                 <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                 <version>2.8</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.10</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                  <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/allure-reports/</outputDirectory>
                    <allureResultsDirectory>${basedir}/target/allure-results</allureResultsDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

I tried running MVN site but that did not work.
Thanks!!

Comment: add your pom.xml in the question.

Comment: also add your selenium test code and what you have tried so far

Comment: added pom.xml above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using old report (Allure 1) together with new adaptor (that is only supported by Allure 2).

You can find the full documentation here https://docs.qameta.io/allure/2.0/#_testng

Also there is working example available https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-testng-example